# CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor<>)' cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model, html-helper

I have a model class I created; a simple POCO class:

```
public class ContactModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Work{ get; set; }        
}
```

Inside a view, I'd like to call and editor for this model:

```
<div class="contact-form">
    @Html.EditorFor(new Map.WebUI.Models.ContactModel())
</div>
```

But I get the error:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0411: The type arguments for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.
>
> Source Error:

How can I invoke an editor for a random class, considering the view is **not** strongly typed to this object type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your view you set at the top `@model Map.WebUI.Models.ContactModel`

Then you need to use the EditorFor this way:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ContactModel())
```

the parameter is a Lamda Expresion.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I don't got that you cannot  change it... so... I think you cannot use EditorFor.
But what you CAN do is use a PartialView and use:

```
@Html.Partial("YourContactView", new Map.WebUI.Models.ContactModel())
```

**EDIT 2**

You can also use the `@Html.Editor(string expression, ViewData data)`... that way you can place the Model to pass to the Editor in the ViewData object.

Comment: I explicitly **do not** want to set the view to be strongly typed to this object type.